# A nice Romanian Olympiad integral (Proof Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

The question is, if $f:[1,\infty)\rightarrow [0,1)$ a non-increasing function with $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$. Then Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}[\int_1^2 f^n(x)+\int_2^3 f^{n-1}(x)+......+  \int_{n-1}^n f(x)]=0.$

**Proof**: Since $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$ then we have For a fixed $\varepsilon>0,\exists$ a sufficiently large $N \in\Bbb N$, such that $|f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2N+1}$ $\forall x>N$.
$$0<f(x)≤M<1,M\in\Bbb R \implies f^n(x)≤M^n<\frac{\varepsilon}{2N+1}\forall n>N$$ for sufficiently large $N$. $\implies \int_i^{i+1} f^n(x)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2N+1}$

Now for $n=2N$ we have,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2N-1}\int_i^{i+1}f^{n+1-i}(x)dx= \sum_{i=1}^{N+1}\int_i^{i+1}f^{n+1-i}(x)dx+\sum_{i=N+2}^{2N-1}\int_i^{i+1}f^{n+1-i}(x)dx< \frac{(N+1)\varepsilon}{2N+1}+ \frac{(N-2)\varepsilon}{2N+1}=\frac{(2N-1)\varepsilon}{2N+1}<\varepsilon $$
This is the desired result.

**I'm little bit confused about my proof**. Somebody please help. **Also tell me if there needs more improvement/correction to make this proof better**. **Thanks in advance**.

**Edited:** because the Codomain was wrong, now **Corrected**.

Comment: If $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[1,2],$ this isn’t true is it? Then for any $n,$ $\int_1^2 f^n=1.$ So, maybe the range is supposed to be $[0,1),$ or maybe $f$ is supposed to be strictly decreasing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so if $0≤f(x)<1$ then is my proof correct? If no tell me please where I'm wrong? BTW thanks

Comment: Fix your question first. I didn’t read your proposed proof because it couldn’t be right. And I might not be able to answer the question even if you fix it, but fixing it might help someone else answer the question.

Comment: And don’t use boldface for more than a few words. It reads as shouting. A simple paragraph break is enough there.

Comment: Thanks for helpful suggestions

Comment: This site is awful, Spending hours by typing characters and at the end no help and rather get deduction of points just waste of time. Every time this happen all my post sucked just lots of hours. Never expected, hopeless

Comment: Yes, it is so hard to get free help online when you state an unsolvable problem. What a nightmare.